# What is the meaning of 2:102?

Tags: tafseer, quran-translation, surat-al-baqarah, sihr

Some translators translate 2:102 as: "(Allah sent these two angels to teach black magic so that people could save themselves from its harms", is this correct? if not than what is the meaning?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a better translation:

> And they followed [instead] what the devils had recited during the
> reign of Solomon. It was not Solomon who disbelieved, but the devils
> disbelieved, teaching people magic and that which was revealed to the
> two angels at Babylon, Harut and Marut. But the two angels do not
> teach anyone unless they say, "We are a trial, so do not disbelieve
> [by practicing magic]." And [yet] they learn from them that by which
> they cause separation between a man and his wife. But they do not harm
> anyone through it except by permission of Allah . And the people learn
> what harms them and does not benefit them. But the Children of Israel
> certainly knew that whoever purchased the magic would not have in the
> Hereafter any share. And wretched is that for which they sold
> themselves, if they only knew.
>
> [Surat Al-Baqarah 2:102](http://quran.com/2/102)

Harut and Marut were angels who were sent to Babylon to test people by performing magic. It was the devils who taught people to use that magic, and not the angels.

Answer (score 0):

In fact they taught people magic to avoid them and to recognize magic and they told people do not use this magic for bad intentions but they learned and misused it and then they saidthat soleman was also a magician and he disbelieved but Allah gives us promise that :{ Assuredly Allah defends those who have believed} hajj 38

And he sais in this verse that solemon wasn’t among the disbelievers.